# Passively extend the physical range of a magnetic sensor two connected coils

Tags: sensor, electromagnetism

I've recently gotten myself an e-bike and it's top speed is limited to 25km/h.

I'd love go faster. Nay! I NEED to go faster! (.. I realise that this will probably stress the motor and battery, but I'm fine with this).

The speed limit is calculated using a hall-effect/magnetic sensor, where the magnet is attached to the spokes of the back wheel, and the sensor; to the frame of the bike.

I should be able to trick the on-board computer by reducing the frequency of the magnet going past the sensor. But.. and here's where you guys come in: the sensor cable is not long enough for me to move it, and I don't want to splice it in order to move the sensor 30-odd centimeters (read: I want the mod to be non-destructive).

So my question is this: would it be possible to fabricate two coils myself and put some wire in-between them – then wrap one coil (output) around the sensor, and stick the other coil (input) somewhere else?.. would the small current being generated by the magnet zooming by be lost in the connecting cable or coils? And how should my coils look?

The drive-train of the e-bike is this bugger: https://www.shimano-steps.com/e-bikes/europe/en/product-information/city-trekking/e5000

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A hall effect sensor may not just be for *limiting* speed, but could be used in the actual realtime control of the motor if it uses something like FOC (field oriented control). If it is used that way (not sure if that's common for E-bikes) then tampering with the signal will completely throw off the motor controller, rather than just unlocking a larger speed limit.

Comment: @nanofarad, the bike monitors the wheel speed for speed restriction. See my answer for a photo of the (modified) sensor arrangement.

Comment: Please note that the speed limit is there for legal and safety reasons. The bike is not structurally verified to go faster than specified legally. Depends on where you live, but in some countries modifying an E-bike to go past the limits is illegal and some jurisdictions are not limited to give you a fine for doing so but also additional tax and insurance consequences as the classification of the vehicle is no longer an E-bike. If you ever have an accident with an illegal bike, the legality of the bike will be determined and the insurance company may refuse to pay anything.

Comment: @Justme, all fair enough but the structurally verified bit doesn't make much sense as it's easy to exceed the restricted speed - particularly on a downhill run where 45 kph wouldn't be too scary. With mid-mounted motor and rear gears the motor doesn't know what speed the bike is going at other than from the sensor. Normally there is no insurance required for (a restricted) e-bike so there would be no insurer to refuse a payout. But that's all beyond electronics anyway.

Comment: @Transistor fair enough about the structural speed. But EU laws may be strict - if the motor does not disconnect at 25 kph, it may be classified as moped or motorbike depending on how fast it goes. Then you have not had the bike officially reclassified and so it means fines driving an unregistered motor vehicle and paying for reclassification. As motor vehicles are taxed, you must pay the tax, retroactively. Motor vehicles must have mandatory traffic insurance which also must be paid, retroactively. Also driving motor vehicles needs a driving licence so better have such a license or pay fines.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is this: would it be possible to fabricate two coils myself and put some wire in-between them – then wrap one coil (output) around the sensor, and stick the other coil (input) somewhere else?.. would the small current being generated by the magnet zooming by be lost in the connecting cable or coils?

No, the losses would be too large. If you could get each of your pickup coils up to 10% efficiency you'd get 1% of the magnet energy out of the second coil and it wouldn't be enough to trigger the sensor.

You can have a look at the [Badass](https://www.badassebikes.com/current-badassboxes/) boxes which send every second pulse to the prox. switch. I'm trying to make one but having difficulty triggering the prox switch with an external coil with a 3 V battery supply.

Have a look at my [mechanical solution](https://www.pedelecs.co.uk/forum/threads/bosch-ebike-mechanical-derestrictor.41764/) (which doesn't work well!).

[image]

*Figure 1. A pair of magnets on a star-wheel (with high rotation friction) gives a pulse to the prox. switch every second revolution of the wheel.*

See [Pedalec Forum](https://www.pedelecs.co.uk/forum/threads/ebike-derestrictor.25266/page-3) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer: the speed is proportional to the battery voltage. Even if you hack the sensors, modify the firmware,...etc the increase in speed is not possible.

Morevoer, the hall sensors provide a timing for switching the stator current at the right angle, they are not for speed measurement - the speed can be estimated, but the main function is the correct timing. With altering, introducing a fake signal on the hall sensors, the motor will stop, jerk it can even burn.

EDIT:

I have read the question again. If this sensor is just an external sensor used for speed calculation then yes, it can be easily hacked.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, Marko. It seems to be a mid-mounted motor with hub gears. The motor probably doesn't know what gear you're in and relies on the rear wheel prox switch to calculate speed. Have a look at the [Badass](https://www.badassebikes.com/current-badassboxes/) boxes which send every second pulse to the prox switch. I'm trying to make one but having difficulty triggering the prox switch with an external coil. Have a look at my [mechanical solution](https://www.pedelecs.co.uk/forum/threads/bosch-ebike-mechanical-derestrictor.41764/) (which doesn't work well!).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: 15mph / 25kph is a reasonable speed for a shared-use path. Not on a shared-use and want to go faster? Pedal harder, there's nothing stopping you from doing that.

In the US (California) we have 20mph Class 1/2 and 28mph Class 3 bikes, and these are definitely uncomfortably fast on shared-use paths (and I say this as both a rider and a walker.) As it is, many trails here (California, again) have long had 15mph speed limits, even before e-bikes were a thing. My point is, that 25kph limit doesn't come from nowhere; it's based on real-world experience.

So I get that you want to go faster. California is a hotbed of e-bike hackery, with some [being built here and offered for sale that can hit 60mph](https://electrek.co/2020/11/16/onyx-rcr-60-mph-electric-moped-gets-major-updates-and-doubles-range/). That certainly isn’t safe or sane. But, sure, there’s plenty of situations where going a bit faster than 25kph doesn’t pose a problem.

Nevertheless, please be respectful of other users who don't share your need for speed. Also be aware that your mods will not be lawful, and you can be subject to fines and other penalties if are unlucky enough to be caught.

That said, you could possibly try moving the sensor and magnet to the crankset. This would increase the distance per pulse, so the assist cut-off would happen later.

Looks like [that sensor is available as a replacement part](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/e-bike-e5000-series/SM-DUE10.html). Maybe buy one for hacking and experimentation?

Comment: I think that the systems from the bigger manufacturers such as Bosch and possibly Shimano might detect a match between "wheel" and crank sensors and may stop with an error code. It does appear to work with older systems.

Comment: I would not put it past them to do that.

Comment: Is the sensor a Hall type or just a reed relay?

Comment: I haven't identified mine yet. The forums mention both.

Comment: I think it could be possible to do a 'sensor-in-the-middle' that would make a synthetic pulse train based on the wheel sensor. At the very least, a gearmotor with a magnet?